# Re-using HTML history state when browser previous/next buttons are clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, browser-history

I'm trying to implement the `HTML5` [history feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to perform AJAX loading of page content. So far my JS looks like this:

```
// saving current page to history
var current_url = "page1"    
var page_content1 = $('body').html();
history.pushState({page_content: page_content}, current_url, current_url);

// loading new page with AJAX
var new_url="page2"
$.getJSON(new_url,get_data,function(data){
    $('body').html(data.page_content);

    var page_content2 = $('body').html();
    history.pushState({page_content: page_content2}, new_url, new_url);
});
```

-**OK:** when the JS is executed the content of "page2" is properly loaded via AJAX into the `body` and the browser `URL` is changed from "page1" to "page2".
-**OK:** when I click the `previous` browser button, the browser `URL` is changed back from "page2" to "page1"
-**NOT OK:** however when I click the `previous` browser button, the page content is not changed to what it used to be for "page1".

**Q: What events should I bind for the previous/next browser buttons, and what `history` method should I use to retrieve the state data after pressing those buttons?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [`history.js`](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/blob/master/demo/index.html) which relies on the `window` `'statechange'` event to handle interactions with browser `previous/next` buttons and the `getState()` method to retrieve the state data.

Comment: best this is support also html5 , what can better ask ?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onpopstate = function (e) {
    if (e.state) {
        // Work with state object here
    }
}
```

Note that if you want the initial page the user visits to load correctly when navigating back to it, you'll need to use history.replaceState() during your initial page load to load a state for that page.

Also note that there are a number of jQuery plugins to do this already.  Some of them even try to support IE (using an iframe).  Before reinventing this yourself, you may want to try some of the existing solutions.